# Python Speech_Recognition - "This audio source is already inside a context manager"

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to run the speech recognition in the background on Linux machine, but it gives me an AssertionError saying "This audio source is already inside a context manager". Everything is working fine, when using it without threading.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import speech_recognition as sr

def speech_to_text(recognizer, audio):
    try:
        print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="de"))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("[!] UnknownValueError")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("RequestError: ", e)

def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(source, speech_to_text)
        #stop_listening()
        #audio = r.listen(source)
        #print(r.recognize_google(audio))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_audio()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your instance of microphone before your context manager 'with'.
Try this

```
def get_audio():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.Microphone()
    with mic as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        try:
           stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(source, speech_to_text)
        except:
            print('please say that again')
            return get_audio()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate it.